# How to Place Shortcuts for Apps Downloaded from Windows Store into Folders

Tags: windows, windows-8, start-screen

I'm trying to organize all of my apps in Windows 8, and I have run into a problem where I can't seem to figure out how to move the shortcuts for Windows 8 apps downloaded from the Windows Store. They don't seem to have any shortcuts in these locations:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

On my screen you can see that I have two apps in the top left, Scan and Skype, that I want to move into the folders on the right but can't figure out how (right-click open image in new tab to see the image larger):

[image]

Here is my folder with all of the other shortcuts on the right:

[image]

Comment: You can't place desktop shortcuts ( or shortcuts within a folder ) to Windows Store applications.  What you see is the actual application ( i.e. not a shortcut to the file ).

Comment: How do I move the application into the proper folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way Windows 8 thinks of Apps versus Applications, you can't really do exactly what you want. Like Ramhound said, what you are seeing in the applications list aren't shortcuts to the applications, but the applications themselves.

You can [make shortcuts to Windows 8 apps](http://www.thinkboxly.com/2012/12/windows-8-app-shortcuts-on-desktop.html), but it's pretty janky.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, maybe they'll make it easier in Windows 8.2

Answer (score 1):

StarDock's product [ModernMix](https://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/) ($4.99) can
run Windows 8 Modern apps in a window on the desktop.

If you can hold off for some months, there are reports that
[Windows 8.2 Revives Start Menu, Runs Metro Apps in Desktop Mode](http://www.dailytech.com/Report+Windows+82+Revives+Start+Menu+Runs+Metro+Apps+in+Desktop+Mode/article33896.htm).